# Building nested routes for a resource that use acts_as_tree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-routes, acts-as-tree

do you know how to generate dynamically routes such as:

```
... (/:parent_id(/:parent_id(/:parent_id(/:parent_id))))/:id
```

I ask this question because I have a `Folder` model which acts as tree (it have a `parent_id` field), and its `to_param` method return its `name` which is uniq through the scope of the `parent_id`. So, each `:parent_id` and event the `:id` are the `name`. Here is an example of path (with 4 sub-folders):

```
/home/desktop/projects/rails/foobar
```

...where the first `:parent_id` (the root) is "home" and the `:id` is "foobar".

Another example of route could be (with 1 sub-folder):

```
/home/music
```

...where, as you can see, `params[:parent_id] == 'home'` and `params[:id] == 'music'`.

Is there a clean way to write a beautiful Rails 3 route which handle those kind of possible nested routes? Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just use a [route globber](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing) and break it up in your controller?

```
# routes.rb
get "/*folders/:id" => "files#show"
```

The `*folders` section will glob up multiple URL segments.

```
# files_controller.rb
def show
  folders = params[:folders].split('/') # gives an array of folder names
  # do whatever else necessary
end
```